# Does increasing Con during level-up also increase the bonus to HP from Con?

Tags: dnd-4e, hit-points

When a player's character increases their Con score at any level does that change their max Hit Points?

For example, a cleric has HP equal to 12+Con at 1st level and has a 16 Con. And at levels 4, 8, 11, and so on I could add +1 to two scores, and I choose Con for one of them every time. So at level 4 the cleric's Con goes to 17, at level 8 it becomes 18 Con, at level 11 it's 19 Con, and so on.

Though it seems small, should I add that +1 my Hit Points as well when my Con increases?

Answer (score 15):

**Yes**

To quote from the Player's Handbook, p. 27, Gaining Levels:

> ## Hit Points
>
> Check your class description in Chapter 4 to see how  many hit points
>   you gain with your new level. Add those  to your total. If you
>   increased your Constitution score,  increase your hit points by 1 (as
>   if you had your new  Constitution score when you were 1st level).
>   Also, if you  increased your Constitution score to an even number, 
>   increase your number of healing surges by one.